# Javascript pause audio playing after x seconds

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio

I first defined a start time for audio playing and an end time both in seconds

```
var a = document.getElementById("audioplayer");
a.addEventListener("progress", function () {
    if ($("#audioplayer")[0].currentTime > Math.round(Number(globalStart) + Number(globalDuration)))  {
        $("#audioplayer")[0].pause();
    }
}, true);
```

I want to stop audio playing when current time reaches x seconds

how can I do that?

Comment: i can't find a event "is currently playing"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add event listener on **timeupdate**

```
a.addEventListener('timeupdate', function () {
    if (this.currentTime > Math.round(Number(globalStart) + Number(globalDuration)) && !this.paused)  {
        this.pause();
    }
});
```